# Facing issue when writing a query on createOrReplaceTempView in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Below is my code in spark structured streaming within `foreachBatch`

```
df.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {

     batchDF.persist

     batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("all_notifis");

      batchDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("api_notifications_topics");

       val meta_data= spark.sql("select topic,partition,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts ,max(off_set) as max_offset from all_notifis  group by topic,partition")

      meta_data.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("api_notifics_metadata");

      batchDF.unpersist()

     }).start().awaitTermination()
```

Even though I created `tempview("all_notifis")`, it is trying to fetch that table from hive default DB and throwing below error

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view `all_notifis` not found in database 'default';

Can anyone help with what is the issue?

Comment: It got resolved.. Instead of ```val meta_data= spark.sql("select topic,partition,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts ,max(off_set) as max_offset from all_notifis  group by topic,partition")``` we have to give ```val meta_data=batchDF.sparkSession.sql(s"select topic,partition,max(off_set) as max_offset, min(off_set) as min_offset,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts from all_notifis group by topic,partition")```

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved.. Instead of val meta_data= spark.sql("select topic,partition,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts ,max(off_set) as max_offset from all_notifis group by topic,partition") we have to give val meta_data=batchDF.sparkSession.sql(s"select topic,partition,max(off_set) as max_offset, min(off_set) as min_offset,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts from all_notifis group by topic,partition")